# How can I get historical weather data for the United States?

Tags: meteorology, open-data

I went to the web site of the [National Weather Service](http://w2.weather.gov/climate/) and clicked around but it was fruitless. How can I get historical weather data in the US?

I want to get daily high and low and precipitation for a particular weather station for time periods such as 1930 to 1940.

Comment: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/isd and ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ are my "go to" sources.

Comment: This [totally off-topic question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200984/where-can-i-find-historical-raw-weather-data) has resources too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This the portal for the NOAA historical records

https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/search

You can specify what you are looking for (Summaries, or other), the time range, the area.

They have records starting in the 1800`s to today.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Regional Climate Center](http://www.wrcc.dri.edu/rcc.html) network for data. There are 6 different climate centers hosted by various research institutes, they each have their own database system for sharing data.

I don't know how it compares to the other linked sources, but what I value about the climate centers is the presence of lots of incomplete records from smaller stations. I'm not sure if those records are available through NOAA, but I do a lot of computer aggregation where more data points is more better.

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite resource for historical climate data http://cdiac.ornl.gov/epubs/ndp/ushcn/ushcn.html

Comment: Note: *CDIAC as currently configured and hosted by ORNL will cease operations on September 30, 2017* and *CDIAC will regrettably no longer be performing annual data updates to our interface for NOAA's USHCN database, with the final year of data being 2014* So this resource is not much use. It points to http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/ for followup